# How to call an object's method by name in Python?

Tags: python

I have a small question:
If I run this:

```
print(list(globals()))
```

this is the output:

```
['__package__', '__loader__', '__doc__', , '__file__', 'b', '__name__', '__builtins__', 'a']
```

I want to try a method with all of these elements, especially `a` and `b`.

But this would be like:

```
'a'.run()
```

so this doesn´t work at all.

I need something like:

```
a.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the string as the key to the dictionary returned by `globals`. The resulting value will be the actual object. Example:

```
a = "hello world!"
print globals()["a"].split()
```

Here, the method `split` is called on the variable `a`. Result:

```
['hello', 'world!']
```

Comment: sorry, thats not what i want. my problem is this:
b=any_class()
now calling globals() into a list, and me wanting to run b isn't possible, because if i do, it tries this:
"b".run()

Comment: @m00lti That's not really a problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @m00lti Yes, so to run something on `b`, you need a reference to the actual object, not a string of the name. That is what Kevin gives you a method of doing in this answer. Please re-read the answer, understand it and try to apply it before writing it off.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that the object is called `a`, just access the variable directly: `a.run()`.

If you don't know the variable name, then you surely don't know if it refers to a value with a `run` method, so it's far from safe to attempt to call it in that way.

Whatever you're trying to do, there is almost certainly a better way.

Answer (score 0):

in this particular case, you're bumping into the way iteration over `dict`'s work.  When you do `list(some_dict)`, you get a list of the *keys* of `some_dict`.  It happens that `globals()` is a dict, and so you get the keys of that dict, the 'names' of the global things.  You can get the *values* from a dict in the obvious way: `list(some_dict.values())`, and you can even get both key and value together with `some_dict.items()`.

So your example could be

```
for something in globals().items():
    something.run()
```

More generally, if you had some arbitrary list of names you need to resolve, you probably don't want to use this sort of approach.